# Cakephp queries sequence get unexpected result

Tags: php, mysql, asynchronous, cakephp, transactions

I have two queries in a Cakephp 2.8.4 model function.

- In the first one I take a record in table A that is not in table B (depending on a key)
- Then I copy that record in table B (only some useful fields, and the key)

These 2 queries are repeated in a for cycle for about 20 times.

In this scenario I don't expect to have in table B two identical records but sometimes it happens; i think for asyncronous calls.
How can I avoid it? I try rounding the two queries in a transaction in this way:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < $number ; $i++ ){
  $dataSource = $this->getDataSource();
  $dataSource->begin();

  $record = $this->getRecord($param1, $param2, ...);
  $this->insertRecord($record['id']);

  $dataSource->commit();
}
```

but it gives me the same result.

Comment: What do `getRecord` and `insertRecord` look like? More importantly, what "unexpected result" do you get?

Comment: It is a pseudo-code, not the real code. Anyway:
getRecord, as I write in the explanation above, take a record in the table A that is not in table B.

insertRecord put that record into table B.

I expect that, in the table B, every records are different. But sometimes getRecord returns some record already inserted in table B. I think it is for a syncronization issue.

Comment: You could add a level of synchronization via locking (whether locking the tables, or a custom "locks" table, or testing existence of a file in the filesystem), to prevent multiple processes from running at once. Or you could add duplicate checking in your validation so that duplicate records don't get created.